# Force line break on url in listings

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I want to list some python code in a file, but I have the problem, that url's are not getting split properly, line break does not seem to work for them. Also, how can I remove the word 'file' from being used as a keyword? I found some solutions online but they do not work.

I made a short example of my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{fullpage}

% colors
\definecolor{nearlyblack}{HTML}{2D2F3D}
\definecolor{nearlywhite}{HTML}{F6F9F0}
\definecolor{lightblue}{HTML}{84D6DD}
\definecolor{yellow2}{HTML}{EFEAAB}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{B195FA}
\definecolor{orange2}{HTML}{FC751C}

\lstset{
    numbers=left, 
    language=Python, 
    columns=fullflexible,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{nearlywhite}, 
    numberstyle=\small\color{lightblue}, 
    escapeinside=||, 
    gobble=10,
    commentstyle=\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{yellow2},
    keywordstyle = [2]{\color{orange2}},
    keywordstyle = [3]{\color{purple}},
    otherkeywords = {<,>,+,-,=,:,.},
    morekeywords = [2]{<,>,+,-,=,:},
    morekeywords = [3]{ur,plt},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true, backgroundcolor=nearlyblack, innerleftmargin=22pt, innertopmargin=0pt, innerbottommargin=0pt]
        \lstinputlisting[breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=true]{test example.py}
    \end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

with the python file

```
import urllib.request as ur
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

url = "https://www.eoiurwnuprenowu.com/e8g8hrw9piuhefg/ohrvwiphwr/fejnridvurb/irwpnevwnvwepjkbhib"
file = ur.urlopen(url)
```

gives the following output:
[image]

Comment: As explained in the listings documentation, the option `breakatwhitespace=true` "allows line breaks only at white space". The URL has no white spaces so it will not break. Remove the option and the URL will break

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know, how to remove 'file' as a keyword? Then, all my problems would be solved

Comment: I suppose you should use the `deletekeywords` option. Anyway for this problem you should open another question

Comment: I tried that already, but it did not work. Can you put your answer under, so I can mark it as the answer to the question? I will open up another question for the other problem.

Comment: Wait, I found the solution, 'deletekeywords=[2]{file}' does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `breakatwhitespace=true` and adding `deletekeywords=[2]{file}` solves the problems.